# how to create logfiles in c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, fstream

I need to create a logfile. I don't know what errors do  have to put in the logfile. 
I have the following code (but I don't know why is not writting to the end of a file)

log.cpp

```
#include "log.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Log::Log(char* filename) {
//ofstream m_stream(filename);
m_stream.open(filename);

}
```

In a test.cpp I have pLOg->Write(c). I don't understand why is rewritting the file and why is not writting at te enf of it.

```
void Log::Write(char* logline)
{
time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  m_stream.seekp (0, ios::end); 
  while ((m_stream.eof())){}
  {
  m_stream <<"current time: "<< asctime (timeinfo) <<" "<< logline << endl;
  }

}

Log::~Log(){

  m_stream.close();
}
```

log.h

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Log {
  public:
    Log(char* filename);
    ~Log();
    void Write(char* logline);
private:
    ofstream m_stream;
};
```

Comment: Related: http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Open with `std::ios::out | std::ios::end`, so you start at the end of the file.

Comment: where should i add it? .open(file,std::ios::out | std::ios::end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m_stream.open(filename, ios_base::app | ios_base::out);
```

Comment: what types of errors should I include here? ad how can I find this errors?

Comment: The mistake you made was technically a logic error and no error code is going to prevent it.  Otherwise, just make sure the file opened properly with something like "if (m_stream)..." or "if (m_stream.open()..."

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor to:

```
Log::Log(char* filename) {
    m_stream.open(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
}
```

More explanation:
http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1040/apped-data-enf-text.htm